# Extended Property -Values for the property we want to assign

Tags: c#

Folder size:

```
   ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_Extended_Message_Size = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3592, MapiPropertyType.Long);
```

All folder type:

```
  ExtendedPropertyDefinition allFoldersType = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(13825, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
```

In this definitions the values(3592,13825) for each property changes. How to know those values for rest all properties?

Comment: Are you looking the the [Microsoft Exchange Property Tags reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526844%28EXCHG.10%29.aspx) ?

Comment: ya...Tag number of each property...In tag reference all are in hexadecimal format but while specifying in the method it's in decimal format.